# Git: what does the "[master $=]" on the terminal mean?

Tags: git, ubuntu, terminal

On my terminal, it either has

```
username@username ~/release[master=]
```

or

```
username@username ~/release[master $=]
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

If this is using the [`contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh), then:

- "`$`" means [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) is [not empty](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9f6f3b6195a0ca35642561e530798ad1469bd41/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L518-L521) (you have content stashed, and `$GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE` is defined)
- "`=`" means [`git remote -v`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) is not empty (you have a remote defined) and [your branch is equals to its remote tracking branch](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9f6f3b6195a0ca35642561e530798ad1469bd41/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L192-L198) (no commits ahead or behind), and `$GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM` is set to `verbose`.